# regex to change a custom word

Tags: javascript, regex

Im working on a translation project, when user types i have to change some words like **"yalama"->"yaLama"**, **"yalamak"->"yaLamak"**, **"kalamadi"->"kaLamadi"**, **"salamadi"->"saLamadi"**, my code works well for now but i have a problem: if i type only **"Lam"**, it is not changing to **"Lm"** as it should be...and I don't know how to write or solve its regex :(

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {
        var text2 = $(this).val();
        text2 = text2.replace(/al/g, "L");
        text2 = text2.replace(/([^L]|^)am/g, '$1m');
        $("#ta_1").val(text2);
     });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28" ></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ***" if i type only "Lam", it is not changing to "Lm" as it should be"*** I don't see that on your code.

Comment: @PedroLobito i posted a code snippet, try to type "Lam", i want to change it to "Lm"

Comment: @PedroLobito you can delete "as it should be" part maybe i made an english mistake ^^

Comment: it works for lowercase `lam`.

Comment: I suppose, for this input string `yalama` the result should look like `yLma`. Don't you think?

Comment: @MB yeah i know but i need to work with uppercase "L"(Lam)  :/

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest nope "yaLama" :/

Comment: your regex sequence is incorrect. How this `"yalama"` can become `"yaLama"` after the replacement `replace(/al/g, "L")` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i changed the sequence but it didn't work :/ for ex: i put `text2 = text2.replace(/al/g, "L");` after the other one but it didnt work :(

Comment: It would be better if you list all the possible corner scenarios along with expected output

Comment: @D_Supreme  i wrote some examples but i can add "talama"->"taLama",,"malama"->"maLama",,"lam"->"lm",, all working...i have a problem only with "Lam"

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the pattern for string replace. Please try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {

    var text2 = $(this).val();

    text2 = text2.replace(/(ya)l(amak?)/g, "$1L$2");
    text2 = text2.replace(/(ka|sa)l(amadi)/g, "$1L$2");
    text2 = text2.replace(/\bLam\b/g, "Lm");

    $("#ta_1").val(text2);


  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much it is enough for me i will try to develop it after, because i have to generalize the code for all cases,,like:xxxxlaxxx->xxxxLaxxx

Comment: That could be done by: `text2 = text2.replace(/la/g, "La")`.

Answer (score 0):

The Regex pattern is looking for a string that does **NOT** contain an upper case `L`. So `lam' evaluates to true. Remove the brackets []`(which negates the letter) and add and `i` for case insensitive

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {

var text2 = $(this).val();

   text2 = text2.replace(/al/g, "L");

   text2 = text2.replace(/(^L|^)am/ig, '$1m');


$("#ta_1").val(text2);
  
  
});
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body>
  
<textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28" ></textarea>
  
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: @M B can you post me a jsfiddle or an example please ?

Comment: I just edited your code replace lines 3-5 with this code

Comment: can you debug? Is it getting into the `else` statement?

Comment: @pinug how do you test it? sorry, a bit new at SO

Comment: @M B no problem..thank you fo your help..there is a button "copy snippet to answer" i copied your code and i ran the code, but it didn t work...

Comment: @M B still not working but thank you for your interest and help